# Show that if $f$ is integrable over $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $f$ is integrable over $S_1-S_2$, and $\int_{S_1-S_2}f=\int_{S_1}f-\int_{S_1\cap S_2}f$. (2)

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be bounded sets in $\mathbb{R}^n$; let $f:S\to\mathbb{R}$ be a bounded function. Show that if $f$ is integrable over $S_1$ and $S_2$, then $f$ is integrable over $S_1-S_2$, and $\int_{S_1-S_2}f=\int_{S_1}f-\int_{S_1\cap S_2}f$.

I got this question from [the link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2716757/show-that-if-f-is-integrable-over-s-1-and-s-2-then-f-is-integrable-over).

@positrón0802 said the in the link:

Recall that given a bounded set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $g:A\to \mathbb{R},$ we define
$g_A:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ by
$$ g_A(x)=\begin{cases}g(x), &x\in A,\\0 & \text{otherwise.}\end{cases}$$

First consider the case in which $f$ is non-negative.
Now let $S=S_1\cup S_2$ and $T=S_1\cap S_2.$  If $f$ is integrable over $S_1$ and $S_2$ then, applying Lemma 13.2 (Munkres Analysis on Manifolds), it is integrable over $S$ and $T$ because $f_S(x)=\max\{f_{S_1}(x),f_{S_2}(x)\}$ and $f_T(x)=\min\{f_{S_1}(x),f_{S_2}(x)\}.$

Now show the following:

- **1)** Show that $f_{S_1-S_2}(x)=\max\{0,f_{S_1}(x)-f_{S_2}(x)\}.$ For this you can consider the cases $x\in T,$ $x\in S_2,$ $x\in S_1-S_2,$ $x\not\in S.$ From this follows that $f$ is integrable over $S_1-S_2.$
- **2)** Show that $f_{S_1-S_2}(x)=f_{S_1}(x)-f_T(x).$ Again you can consider the cases $x\in T,$ $x\in S_2,$ $x\in S_1-S_2,$ $x\not\in S.$ This complete the result if $f$ is non-negative.

Finally, in the general case ($f$ not necessarily non-negative), set
$$ f_+(x)=\max\{f(x),0\} \hspace{.3cm}\text{ and } \hspace{.3cm}f_-(x)=\max\{-f(x),0\}.$$
Both are non-negative and $f(x)=f_+(x)-f_-(x).$

**May you say that how can we show $1)$ and $2)$? Thanks...**

Comment: Presumably you meant to have $S_2$ inside the $\max$ on the 1) line?

Comment: @copper.hat yes, yes. sorry, i am editing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For both 1) & 2) we can look at three cases that cover all relevant possibilities:

(i) $x\notin S_1 $:
$f_{S_1}(x) = 0$, $f_{S_2}(x) = 0$, $f_{S_1 \setminus S_2} (x) = 0$.

(ii) $x \in S_1 \cap S_2$:
$f_{S_1}(x) = f(x)$, $f_{S_2}(x) = f(x)$, $f_{S_1 \setminus S_2} (x) = 0$.

(iii) $x \in S_1 \setminus S_2$:
$f_{S_1}(x) = f(x)$, $f_{S_2}(x) = 0$, $f_{S_1 \setminus S_2} (x) = f(x)$.

It is straightforward to check that the left and right hand side are equal is all cases.

Comment: You didn't choose any rectangle, do we need this to show for $1)$?

Comment: What rectangle are you referring to?

Comment: I looked a proof of '' If $S=S_{1} \cup S_{2}$ and $f$ is integrable over $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$,
then $f$ is integrable over $S$ and $S_{1} \cap S_{2} ;$ '' here, in the proof:

Comment: here, in the proof: Let $T=S_{1} \cap S_{2}$. We prove $f$ is integrable over $S$ and $T$. Consider
frst the special case where $f$ is non-negative on $S$. Let $Q$ be a rectangle
containing $S$. Then both $f_{S_{1}}$ and $f_{S_{2}}$ are integrable over $Q$ by hypothesis. It
follows from the equations

Comment: it follows from the equations: $$
f_{S}(x)=\max \left\{f_{S_{1}}(x), f_{S_{2}}(x)\right\} \text { and } f_{T}(x)=\min \left\{f_{S_{1}}(x), f_{S_{2}}(x)\right\}
$$
that $f_{S}$ and $f_{T}$ are integrable over $Q .$    and continuing...

Comment: but you didn't refer about rectangle in your proof

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood your question, it asked to show 1) & 2). You might want to clarify exactly what you are asking in your question.

Comment: okey okey, I understood now!, thanks.